# K sorted array using priority queue - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, data-structures, priority-queue

I am implementing k sorted array using priority queue in C++. In the output, only the first k elements are sorted but rest are not. Please find the problem in the code.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

void kSortedArray(int input[], int n, int k){
    priority_queue<int> pq;
    for(int i= 0; i < k; i++){
        pq.push(input[i]);
    }

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = k; i < n; i++){
        int ans = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        input[j] = ans;
        pq.push(input[i]);
        j++;
    }

    while(pq.size() != 0){
        input[j] = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
    }
}





int main() {
    int input[] = {10, 12, 6, 7, 9};
    int k = 3;
    kSortedArray(input, 5, k);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << input[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that std provides [`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort).

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Just posting code and asking us to find the problem isn't a very good question. You should tell us what error you're seeing. It the problem is that you're not getting the right output, then show us the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this part (you forgot to increment `j`):

```
    while(pq.size() != 0){
        input[j++] = pq.top(); // <-- this line
        pq.pop();
    }
```

Also your code sorts in decreasing order. If you want to sort in an increasing order, use a minheap:

```
priority_queue<int,vector<int>, greater<int>> pq;
```